# Reome the leading 0 if day and month less than 10, java script?

Tags: javascript

```
function SelectDate(){
    var date = new Date();

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var selecteddate = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;


    document.getElementById('selectActivityDate').value = selecteddate;
}
```

actually , date format in my database is  m/dd/yyyy , eg . 4/21/2015 ,,,,  but from calender  i am selecting like 04/21/2015,,,  so want to remove the ---> 0 from month ,, and same thing for day...

Comment: Which calender you are using?

Comment: sorry , for late ,reply ,,, ,, i am using normal ,date type  ,, calender .... <input type="date" id="selectdate" name="selectdate"> .....

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that

```js
var date = '04/01/2015';
var output = date.replace(/^0|(\/)0/g, '$1');
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much sir for answer and for taking interest in my question  ,, but  have done with different way ,,,,,
in jsp page i normally use

input class="form-control" type="date" id="selectActivityDate"  placeholder="Select date"  name="selectActivityDate" value=""
style="width: 25%; margin-left:25px;height:29px;"

and after in servlet i handle it using

```
date=yyyy-mm-dd;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d");
 newdate=df.format(date);
```

and i got   new date is without leading 0.